# Highcharts: dynamically change the tooltip formatter?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to format a reusable Highcharts tooltip dependent on a global value. (I'm using the same chart to switch between currency and numeric values: if I'm showing currency data on the chart, I want to format the tooltip as currency.)

However, `this` in the Highcharts tooltip function seems to refer to the local data point only, and I don't seem to be able to pass a value in.

How do I either pass a value in, or get a global value? This is my code right now, which fails horribly:

```
getChartTooltip: function() {
    return function(graphType) {
        var prefix = (graphType === 'currency') ? '$' : ''; // Fails
        return prefix + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0);
    };
},

initializeChart: function() { 
  var graphType = 'currency';
  var chartOptions = {};
  chartOptions.tooltip = {
      formatter: getChartTooltip(graphType)
  };
  // create chart, etc... 
  $('change-chart-type').on('click', function() { 
     // Try to update the tooltip formatter, fail horribly...
     graphType = 'number';
     chart.series[0].update({
         tooltip: {
             formatter: _this.getChartTooltip(graphType)
         }
     });
 });
```

What's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to change the `tooltip.formatter`, because it's the `formatter` itself who will change the `tooltip`.

I would try something like :

```
tooltip: {
     formatter: function() {
          var unit = ' $',
              result = this.value;
          if(this.series.name == 'your_currency_serie_name'){
               result += unit;
          }
          return result;
     }
}
```

Where `'your_currency_serie_name'` is the name of the serie which refers to currency values.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `tooltip` options in each series as well via the [`valueDecimals`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.tooltip.valueDecimals), [`valuePrefix`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.tooltip.valuePrefix), and [`valueSuffix`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.tooltip.valueSuffix) options. The `tooltip` will then use these options for displaying the data. Live [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/v827253t/).

Generic setup:

```
...
        series: [{
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 0,
                valuePrefix: '',
                valueSuffix: ''
            },
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }, {
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2,
                valuePrefix: '$',
                valueSuffix: ' USD'
            },
            data: [129.9, 171.5, 1106.4, 1129.2, 1144.0, 1176.0, 1135.6, 1148.5, 1216.4, 1194.1, 195.6, 154.4]
        }]
...
```